# Drawing images off-screen results in performance drop 

Tags: ios, actionscript-3

Im writing an IOS game using AS3.  Here's the problem- I have an image on the screen that moves around.  When the image's y value goes negative (the image is partly off the screen), the frame rates bottom out.  I've gone over my code pretty thoroughly, even threw together a few test projects just to experiment.  In all the test I do, whenever there is an object that is off screen, even partially, the frame rates drop.  It's making scrolling backgrounds impossible.  BTW, I'm using Packager for iPhone and a 3G (not 3GS).  Frame rates are normally 24 with no problems

Comment: Not at the moment, its on a different machine.  Mostly wondering if anyone else had a similar problem or has heard of this.  Will post code when I have access to it

Comment: Disregarding this weird problem you described, I'd recommend you to use BitmapData#copyPixels() for a faster background scrolling (should be especially noticeable on iDevices).

Answer (score 1):

What technique do you use to hide the invisible part of the screen? Mask + scrolling content, scrolling content or scroll rect? You should consider using scroll rect if that's not the technique you are using right now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clip all drawing to the visible image. Anytime you draw offscreen you lose hardware acceleration, which only works on video memory.